# Configuring Swashbuckle

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I'm having problems getting Swashbuckle to run..

**I installed packages:**

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
PM> Install-Package WebActivatorEx
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
PM> Install-Package Swashbuckle.Core
PM> Install-Package Swashbuckle
```

I cant navigate to /swagger... how can I make my api to get swagger?

Comment: Show us the code please. What have you try so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) Will guide you because Microsoft is supporting now.